# Hibernate + C3P0 how to intercept database is unreachable?

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

Good afternoon to everyone,

my question is probably simple but I can't resolve by myself.

I have a j2EE application with Hibernate + C3P0 connection pool.

I have something like this to create a session factory:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","root");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","root");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",dbURL);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
```

All works fine.

If I shut down MySQL and restart the application I get the following message:

***com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source***

but I can't intercept this exception.

The question is:
how can I realize that DB is unreachable at this point?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please configure Connection testing, then c3p0 will self-heal.

See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Note: You are probably using c3p0-0.9.2.1, which does not yet support Connection.isValid(). So please set an efficient preferredTestQuery (via hibernate, `hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery`) for your tests. For MySQL, `SELECT 1` will usually do.